# Conditional .js function in OC 3.x template

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

Hoping to get some ideas with current situation, honestly - I'm poor on .js side, so hopefully you'll be able to put me in a right way.

Checkbox (content is visible if checkbox checked, otherwise hidden):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"  onclick="myFunction()"> {{ text_company_purchase }} 
  <div id="text" style="display:none">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="input-payment-company">{{ entry_company }}</label>
        <input type="text" name="company" value="{{ company }}" placeholder="{{ entry_company }}" id="input-payment-company" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="input-payment-company_code">{{ entry_company_code }}</label>
        <input type="text" name="company_code" value="{{ company_code }}" placeholder="{{ entry_company_code }}" id="input-payment-company_code" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="input-payment-vat_code">{{ entry_vat_code }}</label>
        <input type="text" name="vat_code" value="{{ vat_code }}" placeholder="{{ entry_vat_code }}" id="input-payment-vat_code" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and .js function code:

```
        <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
      var text = document.getElementById("text");
      if (checkBox.checked == true){
        text.style.display = "block";
    $('.payment-company_code input[name=\'company_code\']').addClass('required');
      } else {
         text.style.display = "none";
$('.payment-company_code input[name=\'company_code\']').removeClass('required');
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Probably I'm using wrong syntax of checking is mentioned field required. Unless I need add into controller some conditional checking of that field.
Appreciate for any comments and ideas.
Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to add the class 'required' to the third input? If so, where is the element which has the class "payment-company_code"?

Comment: I'm trying to make company_code field make required if checkbox is checked, so you meaning I'm using wrong string in .js?
Should be input-payment-company_code?

Comment: The correct query selector would be `"#input-payment-company_code[name='company_code']"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input has `id="input-payment-company_code"`, so correct determination in jQuery will be `$('#input-payment-company_code')`, where `#` stands for ID.

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
    var text = document.getElementById("text");
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
      text.style.display = "block";
      $('#input-payment-company_code').addClass('required');
    } else {
      text.style.display = "none";
      $('#input-payment-company_code').removeClass('required');
    }
  }
</script>
```

Although, to set input as `required` we need not only a class, but attribute.

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
    var text = document.getElementById("text");
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
      text.style.display = "block";
      $('#input-payment-company_code').addClass('required');
      $('#input-payment-company_code').prop('required',true); // this will add the attribute `required`
    } else {
      text.style.display = "none";
      $('#input-payment-company_code').removeClass('required');
      $('#input-payment-company_code').prop('required',false); // this will remove the attribute `required`
    }
  }
</script>
```